# SQLite UPDATE performance

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have table that contains 350632 records currently. I have recently added a new column to the table which I am trying to populate using this code in C#:

```
List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
        dbConnect.Open();
        int counter = 1;
        string toExecute = "select * from tempwords";
        string insertQuery = "update tempwords set rownum=@toInsert";

        using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = dbConnect.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand newCommand = new SQLiteCommand(toExecute, dbConnect))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = newCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        listOfInts.Add(counter);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
            dbConnect.Dispose();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(listOfInts.Count.ToString());
        dbConnect.Open();
        int iterator = 0;
        using (SQLiteTransaction transactionx = dbConnect.BeginTransaction())
        {

            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(insertQuery, dbConnect))
            {
                command.Transaction = transactionx;
                while (iterator <= listOfInts.Count - 1)
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toInsert", listOfInts[iterator]);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    iterator++;
                    Console.WriteLine((iterator + 1).ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            transactionx.Commit();
            dbConnect.Dispose();

        }
```

I think the logic is fine and it would all be done properly but the update is so slow(even though I have an index onn the rownum column). Is there any way I can speed it up to some realistic time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're having a performance issue likely due to completing 350000+ update statements.  If you can batchify your update statement it will be much faster

Comment: Can you give advice on how to do that(I tried really but I can't make it work)?

Comment: Your new column what types of values is it getting? is it just an incrementing value?

Comment: Integers incrementing.

Comment: though you did specify doing it in C#, your easiest method would probably be to just make the column an identity column where it will be autopopulated with values

Comment: Can I have 2 of these?(I already have _id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```sql
update tempwords set rownum=@toInsert
```

updates all 360632 rows (with the same value).

When you execute this command 360632 times, you end up updating 122942799424 rows.

If you want to update only a single row with each command execution, you have to tell the database which row that is:

```sql
update tempwords set rownum = @toInsert where _id = @id_of_the_row
```

Comment: I noticed that later and corrected it, it is much faster, yet still slow(took a whole night to update), any suggestions?

Comment: I answered the question you asked. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.